# Identical git rebases produce different hashes

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to figure out why the following would happen. Say I start with a commit history such as the following:

```
97a231c (daughter1, daughter2) ...
b051699 ...
0bfc754 (old-parent) ...
f46661a (new-parent) ...
```

At this point, I check out daughter1 and perform a rebase:

```
git checkout daughter1
git rebase --onto new-parent old-parent
```

which results in the following history:

```
48690c3 (daughter1)
5f745e9 ...
f46661a (new-parent) ...
```

Now, since the last two commits between daughter1 and daughter2 are identical in every detail, I'd expect an identical rebase to beget identical hashes:

```
git checkout daughter2
git rebase --onto new-parent old-parent
```

However, the second rebase gives me:

```
c1cb35b (daughter2) ...
af1e8f7 ...
f46661a (new-parent) ...
```

What would cause the branches in these identical rebases to diverge?

Comment: They were done at different times? The timestamp is part of what gets hashed.

Comment: This is by design. _Any_ change to a commit, including the time it is made, should generate a different commit hash.

Answer (score 2):

Rebases will always produce different hashes even if content is the same, because at least the time when you are creating the revisions (commit time, one of the members of the revision) won't be the same... that's enough to produce different hashes for the revisions.

Comment: So there's timestamp different from the one provided by **git log**?

Comment: Every revision has 2 times. One is the _author_ time, another is the _commit_ time. When you create a new revision, both are the same. After that, every time you cherry-pick this revision on top of another (or rebase it), git will keep the author time... but commit time will be the time when the _new_ revision is created.